# SCNAudioPlayer's audioNode property missing

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, tvos

So, I'm trying to build a little game using Apple's SceneKit and as with all games I need to add some sounds here and there.

Reading trough the documentation the `SCNAudioPlayer` could help with that and it's `audioNode` property would allow me to change the volume of a sound, reverb, etc.

Now, the thing is that even though the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNAudioPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNAudioPlayer/audioNode) clearly states that there's this `audioNode` property on the `SCNAudioPlayer` class, and even though this property appears in the headers of the framework, be it Objective-C:

[image]

or Swift:

[image]

when I try to use it in my code I get this error:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.

After struggling with this more then 3 hours and posting my question here I've managed to find that the problem was that I was not importing the `AVFoundation` framework which is needed so that the `audioNode` property would be exposed.

So a simple

```
import AVFoundation
```

Did the trick.

Thanks!